# API rate limits for IBM's Speech-to-Text

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, speech-to-text

I need to process around 1 million audio files through IBM's Speech-to-Text API. I'm trying to be a good steward and not pummel the API with requests. I'm using their asynchronous https interface through the python SDK and plan to 1) submit a set of jobs, 2) sleep for a few seconds, and 3) check if the jobs have completed. Repeat.

Does anyone know if there are burst limits or daily rate limits for the Speech-to-Text API? There are data limits (100MB to 1GB) per request in the documentation but no mention of rate limits, as far as I can see. This info would help me determine how many jobs to submit at one time and how frequently to check if the jobs have completed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Does https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant-v2#rate-limiting help?  I'm not sure what you mean by their speech-to-text api, do you mean the voice gateway?

Comment: Thanks for the response, Aaron. I am using the speech-to-text service documented here: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/speech-to-text?topic=speech-to-text-about#about. I will look at sending an HTTPS request to the speech-to-text service and see if I get back the `X-RateLimit-Limit` field in the response header mentioned in the link you shared.

Comment: I haven't run into a rate limit in the current script I'm running, so perhaps it won't be an issue for me. I'm not using multiprocessing or threading to submit jobs to the speech-to-text service, so my number of requests may not be super high.

Comment: I sent an http request using curl as outlined here: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/speech-to-text?topic=speech-to-text-http and used the `-v` flag to see the headers. The only fields that were similar to the `X-RateLimit-Limit` are below, so the http header didn’t include any information on the rate limit for this service:

< X-EdgeConnect-MidMile-RTT: 31
< X-EdgeConnect-Origin-MEX-Latency: 101
< X-EdgeConnect-MidMile-RTT: 31
< X-EdgeConnect-Origin-MEX-Latency: 2690
< X-EdgeConnect-MidMile-RTT: 31
< X-EdgeConnect-Origin-MEX-Latency: 101